# Detect Change in UILabel Text

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, nsnotificationcenter

Is it possible to set a Notification for when a UILabel's text property is changed?  I tried the one used for UITextFields when I couldn't find one for a UILabel, but it didn't work.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(posttosocial)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:nowplaying];
```

Comment: Try using key-value observing.

Comment: How would I go about that for a UILabel?

Comment: @userXXXX `[label addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];` then implement the appropriate observer methods on `self`.

Comment: ^Do you have to set a delegate / are frameworks required for that method?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks!  If you could put that down as an answer, I'll accept that!  No framework really required outside of basic.  Just use this method `- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"]) {` and put the code he added in your viewDidLoad

Comment: @user717452 No problem, I've made this an answer. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use key-value observing (KVO):

```
[label addObserver:self
        forKeyPath:@"text"
           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                 | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
           context:NULL];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
        /* etc. */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.2+**

```
let observation = label.observe(\UILabel.text, options: [.new, .old]) { label, change in
        print("\(change.newValue as? String ?? "" )")
    }
```

Call `observation.invalidate()` when done observing.