# Add observer to a label

Tags: ios, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

I want to be notified about label's text change.

I have one label in class `A` and in class `B`. I am changing value of that label and according to that I want to make change in class `A`.

I want to do this with `NSObserver`. I tried so many SO links but I cannot make it work. Can anyone explain me on this?

Similar SO link: [Detect Change in UILabel Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326566/detect-change-in-uilabel-text)

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek what is that?

Comment: Key Value Observing. Accepted answer in the link You provided uses this. http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/ Here's nice explanation.

Comment: @vivek show some code...

Comment: you need to qualify why your question is different to the others. Otherwise it will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Key-value observing**.

**Key-value observing** is a mechanism that enables an object to be notified directly when a property of another object changes.

However, in general **KVO** does not work with `UIKit` classes. Here is what Apple says about it:

> Although the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support
>   KVO, you can still implement it in the custom objects of your
>   application, including custom views. - [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html)

Best way would be to create a custom `UILabel` class and override the `setText:` method. In the implementation post a notification.

#### Implementation Example

1. Create a custom UILabel class and define a notification name.

   ```
   extern NSString *const MyLabelTextDidChangeNotification;

   @interface MyLabel : UILabel
   @end
   ```
2. Override `setText:` method and post notification when text changes.

   ```
   NSString *const MyLabelTextDidChangeNotification = @"MyLabelTextDidChangeNotification";

   @implementation MyLabel

   - (void)setText:(NSString *)newText
   {
       if (![self.text isEqualToString:newText])
       {
           self.text = newText;

           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MyLabelTextDidChangeNotification
                                                               object:newText];
       }
   }

   @end
   ```
3. Do the same with `setAttributedText:` method.
4. Objects that want to be notified about the change of text should register for new notification

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
                                                name:MyLabelTextDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];
   ```

Good Luck!