# Why using this Swift code in Xcode doesn't work?

Tags: swift

Have a problem in Swift. I would like to write a program for the school. For odd tails, A week should be displayed and for even days B week. The date can already read it. But if I always program an ee if condition I always get the error message String. I do not know how to transform it. Can anybody help me further?

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Datum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Monat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Woche: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jetzt = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d"
        Datum.text = formatter.string(from: jetzt)

        let jetzt2 = Date()
        let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
        formatter2.dateFormat = "M"
        Monat.text = formatter2.string(from: jetzt2)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func Check(_ sender: Any) {
        if Datum.text = "3"
        Woche.text = "A-Woche"
    }
}
```

Comment: `if Datum.text = "3"` – comparisons are done with `==`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Datum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Monat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Woche: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jetzt = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d"
        Datum.text = formatter.string(from: jetzt)

        let jetzt2 = Date()
        let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
        formatter2.dateFormat = "M"
        Monat.text = formatter2.string(from: jetzt2)
    }

    @IBAction func Check(_ sender: Any) {
        if Datum.text == "3"{
            Woche.text = "A-Woche"
        } else {
            Woche.text = "B-Woche"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I query several things, eg if Date.text = "1" or "3" ...

Comment: @Theo How many conditions you have? Do you want to check whether Date.text is odd or even?

Comment: I would like to say that it is shown on odd days A week and even B week

Comment: @Theo Check `if (Int(Datum.text!) ?? 0) % 2 == 1 { print("odd") } else { print("even") }`

Comment: @IBAction func Check(_ sender: Any) {
            if (Int(Datum.text!) ?? 0) % 2 == 1 {
                Woche.text = "B-Woche"
                
            } else {
                Woche.text = "A-Woche"
                
        }
    
        
    }

Comment: another question :/
you notice I am new ...

can you also check the app if A or B is week without having to press a button?

Comment: You mean on text change? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326566/detect-change-in-uilabel-text

Comment: Alternatively: Move the code from your Check function to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hey, I've set that you can enter something in a text box and then push a button on a label is transferred. How can I adjust, if I go out of the app and again purely the label stores the entered text and not always reset?